# Theory for a Perpetual Motion Machine based off of Electromagnetic Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, friction, electromagnetic-induction, perpetual-motion

So I was studying for a class and this idea suddenly struck me:

A copper coil having around 3000 turns is wound around a wooden cylinder, forming a solenoid. A very powerful permanent magnet is taken (preferably neodymium). Both of these are hung from unelastic strings from a rigid surface, like a wall, in such a way, that at their initial positions they should be 1mm away from each other. Both of them are then pulled back ad released at the same time.

Now, due to Lenz' Law, the induced current opposes the cause, so when the magnet and the solenoid begin moving toward each other, they will be repelled, and if they start moving away from each other, they are attracted, forming a positive feedback loop. In theory this motion should go on forever, right

The magnet taken should be powerful enough to overcome friction.

Comment: For starters copper isn't magnetic. Even if it was a perpetual motion machine is impossible. Figuring out why perpetual motion machines are impossible is fun, at least to me. So don't stop trying just make sure you know why it can't work.

Comment: More on [E&M perpetual motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/em+perpetual-motion).

Comment: It is not exactly clear what your question is. What exactly are you trying to ask, here?

Answer (score 2):

It's a lovely idea, but it won't work forever. The amplitude of the displacement of the coil and magnet will gradually reduce through the loss of energy to frictional forces until the two just hang next to each other motionless.

You have to bear in mind that the repulsion between the  magnet and the coil is a result of their relative motion, so as the motion reduces (as a consequence of friction) so will the repulsive force, which means that over time the two objects will come to a rest.

When you say the magnet is strong enough  to 'overcome' friction, that means the magnet is capable of generating a force that is greater than friction provided the relative speed of the magnetic and coil is large enough. But even if you overcome friction, friction continues to dissipate energy.

Comment: I see, so the only way to do this would be in a vacuum chamber right

Comment: but in that case, a normal pendulum is in itself perpetually moving in a vacuum so kinds beats the point

Comment: Even a normal pendulum in a vacuum will eventually come to a stop because of frictional losses via its pivot, Akuno.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, here is why.

I will assume that your coil is *shorted*- that is, its ends are soldered together so it forms one continuous loop.

When the coil approaches the magnet, the magnet induces a current to flow in the coil and the magnitude of that current is proportional to their speed of approach. That induced current creates a magnetic field which opposes the other magnet, striving to reduce their speed of approach.

In the meantime, the induced current flowing in the coil is dissipated by resistive losses in the wire which go like the square of the current.

The upshot is that this system will continually dissipate the kinetic energy of the swinging magnet and coil into heat in the wire and rapidly bring their relative velocity to zero.

So, no perpetual motion. Sorry.